# Using GetField<T> to set values in an object from a DataRow

Tags: c#, generics, ado.net, datarow

I'm trying to write a generic method to return values from columns in a DataRow.

```
    protected static T GetField<T>(DataRow row, string name, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (row == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("row");
        }

        T result = defaultValue;
        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(name) && !row.IsNull(name))
        {                
            result = row.Field<T>(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When trying to assign values to specific tests I get 'Specified cast is not valid.' exception.

```
var rule = new MyObj
{                   
    AString = GetField(row, "AnswerId", "test"),
    AnInt  = GetField(row, "Decline", 0),
    ADecimal = GetField(row, "LoadFactor", 1M),                                     
};
```

I'm trying to avoid writing an overload for each type.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is 'LoadFactor' decimal in database?

Comment: If declined is bit in database you need to have boolean passed as third argument to getField method.

Comment: You can use object instead of generics and cast appropriately at object creation. Have you considered this?

Comment: @Jenish. yes, but the int is also giving the error

Comment: @sphaso, yeah.  I just wondered if it could be done this way.

Comment: Hm, rereading the code... doesn't just GetField<MyType>(row, "...", "...") work?

Comment: @sphaso: GetField<int>(row, "Decline", 0) - states Type argument specification redundant when compiling - so I gyuess that is what its doing but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `declined` declared as int in the database?

Comment: Yeah I'd check what are the actual types in the DataRow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these extension Methods to convert whole `DataTable` to List, instead of writing method for `DataRow`:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
    {
        public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
        {
            List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
            List<T> result = new List<T>();

            foreach (var row in table.Rows)
            {
                var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
                result.Add(item);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, List<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
        {
            T item = new T();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    if (row[property.Name] != DBNull.Value)
                        property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
                }
            }
            return item;
        }
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
List<SomeType> list = SomeDataTable.ToList<SomeType>();
```

But you have to make sure that name of columns that are selected in query should match the class properties and **datatypes** should also match.